# Google assistant on Amazon Fire stick TV

Tags: google-assistant, amazon-fire-tv

I wanted to know if we can replace the search assistant on Amazon Fire stick TV with Google assistant.
The search assistant that comes preloaded on fire TV is not so good so is there any way to replace it such that when I press mic button it launches Google assistant.